# Looking for Bugtracker with specific features

Tags: bug-tracking

we're looking into bugtracking systems at our firm. We're quite small (4 developers only). On the other hand we have quite a large number of customers we develop individual software for. Most software is built explicitly for one customer, apart from two or three standard tools we ship.

To make support easier for us (and to avoid being interrupted by phone calls all the time) we're looking for a bugtracker that must support a specific set of features.

We want the customers to report bugs/feature/change requests themselves and be notified about these reports by email. Then we'd like to track what we've done and how much time it took, notifying the customer about that per email (private notes for just us must be possible). At the end of the month we'd like to bill all closed reports according to the time it took to solve/implement them.

The following must be possible:

1. It must have a web based interface where the users must log in with credentials we provide. The users must not be able to create accounts themselves/we must be able to turn off such a feature.
2. We must be able to configure projects and assign customer logins to these projects. The customers must only see projects they are assigned to, not any other projects. Also, customers must not "see" other customers. We would name the projects, so that standard tools are listed as separate projects for each customer.
3. A monthly report must be available that we can use to get information about the requests we worked on per customer.

I'd like to introduce some standard product like Mantis (I've played with that a little, but didn't quite figure out whether it provides all the features I listed above). The product should be Open Source and work on a XAMPP Windows Server 2003 environment.

Does anybody have any good suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered Trac ? http://trac.edgewall.org/

Comment: Mantis provides 1. and 2., and it has some reporting, although I'm not sure it will cover 3. completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BugTracker.NET](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html) provides 1 and 2.  Regarding 3, it allows you to extend it by creating your own reports.  You just write some SQL.   It runs on Windows Server 2003.   It doesn't need XAMPP.   It would use the free Microsoft tools, IIS, .NET, and SQL Server Express.

Comment: This looks promising - thanks, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

How about Eventum? http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/other/eventum/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) , made by Atlassian.  The billing component can be managed by doing a monthly search I suspect.  The private comments can be handled via what they refer to as notifications schemes.

-Jay